# Access Twig Extention function in Twig view

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I try to get access to a Twig Extention function I have written.

```
// AppBundle/Twig/AppExtention.php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
  public function getFunctions() {
    return [
      new \Twig_Function('testMethod', 'testMethod'),
    ];
  }

  public function testMethod() {
    return 'blubb';
  }
}
```

Now I try to access the funtion by `{{ testMethod() }}`, but I get the following error:

`UndefinedFunctionException in <Hex for cached view>.php line 68: Attempted to call function "testMethod" from the global namespace.`

I cleared the cache and tried to search for the error, but I found nothing that helped me. Maybe here can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your `Twig_Function` wrong, as it stands now, you told `Twig` to look for a `global function`, defined outside any class.

If you want to tell `Twig` to look inside the current class, you can do this with:

```
public function getFunctions() {
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('testMethod', array($this, 'testMethod')),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, yes, in my case I have to use the ``Twig_SimpleFunction``. Thank you!